# Gloud deploy - container failed to start

Tags: gcloud

docker build -t "us.gcr.io/ek-airflow-stage/array_data:sree" .
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.7
---> 869a8debb0fd
Successfully built 869a8debb0fd
Successfully tagged us.gcr.io/ek-airflow-stage/array_data:sree

**docker push "us.gcr.io/ek-airflow-stage/array_data:sree"**
The push refers to repository [us.gcr.io/ek-airflow-stage/array_data]

a36ba9e322f7: Layer already exists
sree: b size: 2218

gcloud run deploy "ek-airflow-stage" \

> ```
>         --quiet \
>         --image "us.gcr.io/ek-airflow-stage/array_data:sree" \
>         --region "us-central1" \
>         --platform "managed"
> ```

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [ek-airflow-stage] in project ["project"] region [us-central1]
/  Deploying... Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

```
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Comment: Please tidy your list and ask a question. The errors are explanatory. The container failed to start correctly on port 8080. Check the logs to learn why. If the logs are unclear, include details in your question.

Comment: You _may_ also want to consider removing any erroneous or identifiable information from your questions and answers in the future (such as your Google Cloud Platform project ID).